# creating a dynamic html form using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html form that I would like to be pre-populated with data from an sql table depending on which link is pressed onto the get to the table. For example (the form is for updating a table that has different events in it) if I were to click on the link to edit the details of a football match the form would come pre loaded with the details of the football match making it easier for the user.

The php script that bring up the links to the edit table-
include 'database_conn.php';      // This links to the php script which makes db connection

```
include 'database_conn.php';      // This links to the php script which makes db connection

$sql = "SELECT eventID, eventTitle FROM AE_events ORDER BY eventID";

$result = $dbConn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<p>". $row["eventID"]. " <a href='editTable.php'>" . $row["eventTitle"] . "</a></p>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$dbConn->close();
?>
```

The table that I would like to come pre-loaded with data-

```
<form>
<form id="eventEdit" action="View_Events3.php" method="get">
    Event title <input type="text" name="eventTitle" accesskey="f"/><br/>
    Event venue <select accesskey="g">
    <option value="theatre royal">Theatre royal</option>
    <option value="baltic centre for contemporary art">BALTIC Centre For Contemporary Art</option>
    <option value="laing art gallery">Laing Art Gallery</option>
    <option value="the biscuit factory">The Biscuit Factory</option>
    <option value="discovery mueseum">Discovery Mueseum</option>
    <option value="HMS calliope">HMS Calliope</option>
    <option value="metro radio arena">Metro Radio Arena</option>
    <option value="mill volvo tyne theatre">Mill Volvo TYNE Theatre</option>
    <option value="playhouse whitley bay">Playhouse Whitley Bay</option>
    <option value="shipley art gallery">Shipley Art Gallery</option>
    <option value="steven stories">Steven Stories</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    Event Category <select accesskey="h">
    <option value="carnival">Carnival</option>
    <option value="theatre">Theatre</option>
    <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="exhibition">Exhibition</option>
    <option value="festival">Festival</option>
    <option value="family">Family</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="dance">Dance</option>
</select> <br/>
    Event start date <input type="date" name="eventStartDate" accesskey="i"/><br />
    Event end date <input type="date" name="eventEndDate" accesskey="j"/><br />
    Event price <input type="number" name="eventPrice" accesskey="k"/><br />
    Event description <textarea style="width:500px; height:120px;" accesskey="l"></textarea ><br />
```

Comment: I've realised I made a minor mistake- "The php script that bring up the links to the edit table- include 'database_conn.php'; // This links to the php script which makes db connection" should not include my connection and comments this should be formatted as code

Comment: You can edit your question and fix it.